# Regular expression to grab word before a certain character R Perl

Tags: regex, perl, r

I need to get words before and after a unique character (in my case: &) in a string in R.

I need to get 'word1' from something like this:
"...something something word1 & word2 something..."

I can get the word after using a Perl regular expression in R: `(?<=& )[^ ]*(?= )`
(It seems to behave the way I would like. I got it from combing answers I found on this site)

I now need to get the word preceding the `&` symbol. The length of the words change and the number of other preceding words, and also spaces, change. Word one could be letters and numbers, just bound by spaces on either side.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you use `(\S+)\s*&\s*(\S+)` then the words both sides of `&` will be captured. This allows for optional whitespace around the ampersand.

You need to double-up the backslashes in an R string, and use the `regexec` and `regmatches` functions to apply the pattern and extract the matched substrings.

```
string  <- "...something something word1 & word2 something..."
pattern <- "(\\S+)\\s*&\\s*(\\S+)"
match   <- regexec(pattern, string)
words   <- regmatches(string, match)
```

Now `words` is a one-element list holding a three-item vector: the whole matched string followed by the first and second backreferences. So `words[[1]][2]` is `word1` and `words[[1]][3]` is `word2`.

Comment: If anyone in the future is trying something similar, initially this worked but eventually I came across conditions where this grabbed multiple words for some reason. The white space around the ampersand was one of the only consistent conditions so I ended up using: (?<=& )(\\w+) for right of ampersand and (\\w+)(?= &) for to the left.

Comment: @GregS: The only reason I can think of for that is if you are processing text that uses the no-break space `"\x{A0}"`. You can fix that by using `([^\s\xA0]+)\s*&\s*([^\s\xA0]+)` instead. Note that that is the Perl syntax. I know very little about R and that may or may not be the right way to add a character using its code point.

Comment: The first lower case s needs a doubled backslash or R will throw an error. Otherwise this is exactly the answer I need for a project!

Answer (score 5):

```
(?<=&)(\w*)(?=&)"
```

Will match anything that is a word character between `&` symbols. Uses a positive lookbehind and a positive lookahead.

Answer (score 2):

```
\b(.*?)\b&
```

The word will be captured in group 1.  This is a reluctant match contained in any string surrounded by two boundaries; after the second boundary is `&`.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with a relatively simple regular expression using `strapplyc` in the [gsubfn package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=gsubfn).  Assuming `s` is your string:

```
library(gsubfn)
strapplyc(s, "(\\w+) & (\\w+)")
```

Comment: It ;did work at the time of the post 7 years ago. I have replaced it with a link to its CRAN page.